# Add Login provider to meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor

I need to use an in-house user management system to authenticate my users. This system also holds the user's membership to groups and roles and tenants which is most useful when doing the authorization stuff.

I looked at the code for [accounts-persona](https://github.com/vladikoff/meteor-accounts-persona) but it does not work for me. Hence I deduce that I am doing something wrong.

On the server there is a new LoginHandler:

```
Meteor.startup( function () {
   var config = Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.findOne( {service: 'sertal'} );
   if ( !config ) {
      Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert( { service: 'sertal' } );
   }
} );

Accounts.registerLoginHandler( function ( options ) {
   if ( !options.sertal && !options.assertion )
      return undefined; // don't handle

   var url = "http://dev.sertal.ch/checkCredential";
   var request = {
      params: {
         uname: options.email,
         pword: options.password
      }
   };
   var result = Meteor.http.get( url, request );

   if ( result.statusCode !== 200 ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error( Accounts.LoginCancelledError.numericError, 'Sertal Login Failed' );
   } else {
      var user = result.data.userrec;
      user.groups = result.data.grprec;
      user.id = user._id;
      return Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService( 'sertal', user );
   }

} );
```

On the client I use this code after the login button has been pressed:

```
Accounts.callLoginMethod( {
   methodName: 'login',
   methodArguments: {sertal: true,
      email: $( '#sertal-email' ).val(),
      password: $( '#sertal-password' ).val(),
      resume: false
   },
   userCallback: function ( error ) {
      if ( error ) {
         console.log( "error: " + error );
      } else {
         $( "#sertalLoginFormDiv" ).dropdown( 'toggle' );
      }
   }
} );
```

But it does not trigger the LoginHandler. There must be something missing but I can't figure it out.

I could not find any documentation on the subject. An answer could also be to point out some documentation which explains the process.

Comment: Sorry I can't help I'm learning meteor, any news on this? Did you manage to add a new service?

Comment: I did not really investigate any further. I ended up creating a local Meteor user for the remote user with a generated password (the id of the user object). This is still on my list of things to do. Maybe it's in the meteor book

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing, the methodArguments must be an array of objects.

Also, from what I see in the logs, if methodArguments object includes a password at the root of the object, then Meteor throws an error with "Failed Login { type: 'password',..."

I was able to make this work by putting all of the handler's arguments as part of an object.
Something like this, on the client:

```
loginRequest = {myLogin:{email: email, password: password}};
Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodArguments: [loginRequest],
    userCallback: callback
});
```

When executed on the client, meteor calls my server code:

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler( function("someName", loginRequest{
    if(loginRequest.myLogin){
        // I get the loginRequestObject, and can attempt to sign in...
    }
});
```

Note, I am using Meteor 1.0.